# Are there any good free .Net network libraries? (FTP, SFTP, SSH, etc.)

Tags: .net, open-source, ftp, ssh, sftp

I'm a bit surprised I haven't found a good open source library for performing common network tasks. There are a few very good commercial libraries, but they're too expensive to use on an open source project.

Anyone know of any?

Answer (score 30):

SSH.NET Library - https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET

Inspired by Sharp.SSH, this library is complete rewrite using .NET 4.0, without any third party dependencies and utilizes parallelism as much as possible to allow best performance.

It's been a solid C# implementation of client side SSH.

Comment: Much better implementation than SharpSsh and actively being developed. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 4):

[edtFTPNet](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/overview.html) is free, but you have to buy their "Pro" version to get SFTP (FTP over SSH) and FTPS (FTP over SSL).

Answer (score 4):

Although it hasn't been updated in a while, it is free!  I remember being able to get SharpSSH to run without much hassle, and it supports port forwarding (which is what I was looking for at the time!).

SharpSSH
http://www.tamirgal.com/home/dev.aspx?Item=SharpSsh

Comment: It claims to support publickey authentication but I could never get that part to work.  The other basic SSH features worked fine though.

Comment: Public key authentication works fine for me, but there are many (MANY) bugs in other areas...

Comment: Someone has been working on this at CodePlex ( http://sharpssh2.codeplex.com/ )  I haven't really used it though.  Still trying to find a better solution.

Comment: We have found bugs (mainly unfinished parts) too

Comment: SharpSSH is not perfect, but it is the best free SFTP library for .NET.

Answer (score 4):

.Net ships with some basic FTP support via System.Net.FtpWebRequest, but its a bit crude at best. A far superior alternative that I can recommend is [dotNET FTP client from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetftpclient/).

I don't know if you're looking for email libraries too, but its something that I came across, so I'll mention it.

For email composing and delivery, the basic .NET libraries are fine. System.Net.Mail.MailMessage is great for composing emails, and System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient is good for sending emails over SMTP.

For retrieving emails with POP3 and parsing MIME messages, you will want an external library.
I've been using [POP3 MIME Client](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MimeClient.aspx) from codeproject without any problems.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a single library, and I'm not sure how good they are but I was able to find a couple of links to open source libraries here:

http://csharp-source.net/open-source/network-clients

Hope this helps!
Jeff

Answer (score 2):

[Lumisoft](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/Download/Downloads/Net/) is open source and has FTP, DNS, IMAP, POP3 clients, among other stuff. It doesn't include SSH and SFTP though.

Answer (score 1):

- All-singing-all-dancing solution which looks good to me, but which I haven't tried: http://www.nsoftware.com/products/component/sftp.aspx
- SSH / SFTP library which my company uses:  http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-sftp.php

In practice, the only place where I currently do SFTP, I use [putty's](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) bundled psftp utility, and run it from a process object.  That may not be great, but it's working reliably for me.

Comment: Original poster wanted free and open source code.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, FTP is built in to .NET, (System.Net.FtpWebRequest) and last time I looked (a couple of years ago, admittedly) I couldn't find any free SSH / SFTP assemblies.  That might have changed, though.

Comment: FtpWebRequest has some limits/issues for non-standard ftp servers - like those used by certain large nameless banks for ACH uploads. If the ftp server provides a single unexpeced response, it just throws and exception and dies and you can't get around it.

Comment: The FtpWebRequest class is only for the request, though. It doesnt do anything to facilitate file transfer or connection management. I would not consider it a fully functional library for FTP.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found an implementation of SSH in C#, called [sharpSsh](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharpssh.aspx). It is a port of the Jsch (Java Secure Channel) library for Java. We use Jcsh here at my employer, and it's great. I can't vouch for the C# version.

Comment: SharpSSH sucks, and doesn't work. Trust me, I've tried it. I'm serious, it fails on the simplest of scenarios with no error or explanation. That thing needs to be wiped off the internet like a brown underwear stain.