# Upload Download files from FTP site using SFTP

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp, sharpssh

I need to know a way to connect to a FTP site through SFTP. I am using `SharpSSH` and i am unable to find an example to do the program.

For now, i have downloaded the `SharpSSH` `.DLL` files and added as references. Now i need to write the code where i could connect, and upload/download files from the FTP server.

How can i do this ? Help.

**UPDATE**
[image]

Code :

```
//ip of the local machine and the username and password along with the file to be uploaded via SFTP.
 FileUploadUsingSftp("http://Some-sftp-site.com", "username", "password", @"D:\", @"name.txt");
```

The above code is in the Main Method.

Then ;

```
private static void FileUploadUsingSftp(string FtpAddress, string FtpUserName, string FtpPassword, string FilePath, string FileName)
        {
            Sftp sftp = null;
            try
            {
                // Create instance for Sftp to upload given files using given credentials
                sftp = new Sftp(FtpAddress, FtpUserName, FtpPassword);

                // Connect Sftp
                sftp.Connect();

                // Upload a file
                sftp.Put(FilePath + FileName);

                // Close the Sftp connection
                sftp.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sftp != null)
                {
                    sftp.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it an FTP site, or an SFTP site, or a FTPS site?  They are 3 different things.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with DNS resolution.  Can your machine successfully resolve the name of your SFTP server to an IP address?

Comment: Are you changing the username and password to the FTP's username and password.

Comment: Can someone tell me what i should pass for `string FilePath, string FileName` ? Is `FilePath` the path to be found in the SFTP server ? and `FileName` is the file that will be saved in the server ?

Comment: Use this - it is GREAT! http://stackoverflow.com/a/5423005/966609

Comment: Follow C# code snippet that uses Tamir.SharpSSH.dll to assist in uploading file over SFTP. [SFTP – Upload file](http://technowide.net/2012/09/21/sftp-upload-file/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you done as of right now?

We can't just give you a straight answer on 'how to upload files'....

Here is a tutorial: 
http://saravanandorai.blogspot.com/2012/01/sftp-and-file-upload-in-sftp-using-c.html

Comment: First i would need to establish a connection to the SFTP server. and then download the files to a local directory

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial I provided. It has everything your asking for.

Comment: I have updated my question. I get an exception when i do it according to the tutorial. Can you help me solve this 
?

Comment: Can someone tell me what i should pass for `string FilePath, string FileName` ? Is `FilePath` the path to be found in the SFTP server ? and `FileName` is the file that will be saved in the server ?

Comment: If you look in the method the comments clearly show the FilePath and FileName are concated together which represent the full pathname to the location of the file you are wanting to upload.

Comment: How can i download files.. I tried this `sftp.Get(FilePath + FileName , "C://");` But, i end up getting an Exception.

Comment: Just do this sftp.get(@"PATH TO FILE");

Comment: No it should be Uppercase `G`et(@"Path to file"); and then i get this exception --> `Tamir.SharSsh.jsch.SftpException`. Any clue how to solve this ?

Comment: lol i didnt actually mean to write 'path to file' i meant write the full path to the file you want to upload.

Comment: Yes yes... it was `/usr/home/somedirectory`. i did understand that. anyway i get the above error. Actually i am trying to download the file to my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `FtpAddress` parameter should be without `ftp` or `http`, so try the following:

```
 FileUploadUsingSftp("Some-sftp-site.com", "username", 
                     "password", @"D:\", @"name.txt");
```