# SFTP Using .NET

Tags: asp.net-4.0, sftp

I would like to access a file through SFTP using .NET.  I have seen other questions on Stack Overflow regarding this, such as [SFTP question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179569/net-open-source-code-for-sftp), but these are rather old and things would have moved on since then.  My question is, does .NET support SFTP now (it didn't back when this question was asked).  If it doesn't, is there any good Open Source SFTP library that I can use?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899324/upload-download-files-from-ftp-site-using-sftp otherwise it looks like your only other solution is to implement it yourself.

Comment: SFTP for .Net examples can be found at http://sftpcomponent.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, .NET doesn't support SFTP. Your best bet for open source is SharpSSH.

Our own commercial .NET SFTP library, [edtFTPnet/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/overview.html), is built on an open source SSH library, Granados, which could be another alternative.