# SSH connection through Tamir.sharpSsh is not creating

Tags: c#, networking, ssh, client-server, sharpssh

I have made an application, which connects to the device using SSH connection as we do using [PUTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) software.
In my application I have used Tamir.sharpSsh C# library.It gives an exception at making SSH connection. I don't know that either it is a problem of library or device response or something else.

Below is the code.

```
using Tamir.SharpSsh;

                        var obj = new SshStream(ip, username, password); // exception here
                        obj.Write("ls -a");
                        string rS = obj.ReadResponse();
                        richTextBox.Text = rS;
```

Here is the Exception

```
Exception : System.IO.IOException
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect(Int32 connectTimeout)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect()
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.SshStream..ctor(String host, String username, String password)
```

I can also provide the Wireshark data if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Tamir.SSH is broken and doesn't work. The only open source SSH library for .Net currently is SSH.Det. You can find it at this link: http://sshnet.codeplex.com/
Have a look at this SO question: [Are there any good free .Net network libraries? (FTP, SFTP, SSH, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153220/are-there-any-good-free-net-network-libraries-ftp-sftp-ssh-etc)

Comment: This link is going to a redirect page, and that library requires special build tools making it much less useless.