# FTPWebRequest - Active Mode with specific port

Tags: c#, ftp, ftp-client

I would like to connect to a FTP-Server which works in the 'active-mode'. This means, the client can send the port number, on which the data-connection should be done. Usually this is a random port. (N > 1023)

In our case, it would be really nice, if we could always use a specific port for the connection to the FTP-Server. Something like '8232'.

Is this possible?

This is my code:

```
FtpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
            FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + "OurDomainOfTheFTP" + "/"));
            ftpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.benutzer, this.passwort);
            ftpWebRequest.Timeout = 5000;
            ftpWebRequest.UsePassive = false; 

            ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

            WebResponse webResponse = ftpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            webResponse.Close();
```

Can i just write something like that?

```
 FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + "OurDomainOfTheFTP" + ":8232/"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the port you supply to `FtpWebRequest.Create` is the *command port*, not the *data port*. In your initial example the port is omitted, causing it to default to 21.

It seems `FtpWebRequest` does not support specifying a port number for the data connection, see [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/bc1e643a-75b4-4176-98c9-16d75daf6764/ftpwebrequest-specify-a-data-port-to-use).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153220/are-there-any-good-free-net-network-libraries-ftp-sftp-ssh-etc) contains some alternative FTP (and other protocols) clients that perhaps are able to specify this.

Comment: Is there any solution to set the data port? Is this library maybe the right one? http://netftp.codeplex.com/

Comment: @MaxLebold afraid I haven't tried this with any of them myself.

Comment: Ok. I've implemented a solution where i can set a range of data-ports. Now my problem is, that a connection, which was closed, is not really closed an the port is still in use. I get the error: The specific adress is already in use.